# Metodos POST e GET em C#

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, post, get

Gostaria de saber se possui alguma biblioteca ou algum componente de terceiros que façam o POST e GET nos sites. 
Estou precisando navegar em alguns sites porem não consigo fazer o GET nem na página inicial de um site especifico, ele sempre me retorna o erro 599.

Tentativas:

```
 private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string html = client.DownloadString("http://aplicacao2.jt.jus.br/dejt/");
    }

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://aplicacao2.jt.jus.br/dejt");

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

As duas tentativas me retornam essa mensagem de erro:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (599)
>   Unknown Reason."

Já tentei todos os metodos deste link e todos dão o mesmo erro.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Fiz o teste pelo Postman (uma extensão do chrome que realiza esses metodos) e funcionou normal.

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta suas tentativas de código?

Comment: Se o `HttpClient` não funciona, o problema nao está na ferramenta - está no modo como a usas. E a não ser que fornecas um [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), não te podemos ajudar.

Comment: Tentativas adicionadas   @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: @lucasc01 Me parece ser um problema específico do servidor onde está pegando. Não tem nada errado com seu código. Mas o servidor espera alguma forma de requisição que não ocorre usando estas classes. Você precisa descobrir o que está faltando para atender a necessidade específica. A página abre normalmente, estes códigos leem outras páginas. O erro é consistente nas duas formas. Talvez ele espere por um *user-agent* ou alguma coisa que o *browser* costuma fornecer por padrão. Talvez seja proposital para evitar que as pessoas peguem o conteúdo automaticamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que esse site requere a presença do header `User-Agent`. Então basta escolher um (eu usei o user agent do Curl no exemplo abaixo).

O browser, o Curl e o Postman usam o seu próprio UserAgent. As bibliotecas não usam nenhum - por isso é que as tuas tentativas estavam a falhar.

```
public async Task Method()
{
    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        DefaultRequestHeaders =
        {
            {"User-Agent", "curl/7.30.0"},
        }
    };

    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://aplicacao2.jt.jus.br/dejt/");

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Eis um excerto do comando `curl http://aplicacao2.jt.jus.br/dejt/ -vIX GET`, para comparação:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0xd6e590
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0xd6e590) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to aplicacao2.jt.jus.br port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 201.49.155.48...
* Connected to aplicacao2.jt.jus.br (201.49.155.48) port 80 (#0)
> GET /dejt/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: aplicacao2.jt.jus.br
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado! @dcastro